# Symmetry in Space

Tags: symmetry

Is it possible for a non-co-planar set of points to be symmetric about a point but not symmetric about a plane?

I am pretty sure this is true but I can't think of an example.

Things that I think don't work:

- Sphere
- Cone
- Pyramid
- Cube
- Prisms
- cylinder
- hedrons (tetrahedron, dodecahedron, polyhedron, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a letter $F$ in the plane $x=1$ and its reflection through the origin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is not possible because a non-co-planar set of points to be symmetric about a point but not symmetric about a plane is not possible in your situation.